# $ \overline{B}^2 / S^1 \cong S^2$

Tags: general-topology

Prove that $ \overline{B}^2 / S^1 \cong S^2$.

I tried to define a continous map from $ \overline{B}^2 $ to $ S^2 $ (and hence quotient map because $ \overline{B}^2 $ is compact and $ S^2 $ is hausdorff), but my ideas are only related to spherical coordinates which seems too complicated.

Comment: Map [-1,1]/{-1,1} to a circle with x = cos pi.t, y = sin pi.t and rotate that to get a sphere.

Comment: Alright, I understand the idea, and I'll try to write it formally. Thanks